# How to parse a comma seperated variable into array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have defined the variable which contains the even number of comma seperated values with NULL values and the string length varies.

```
var a = '1, 2, 3, 4, 9, NULL':
```

How can i parse these into array like

```
a[0] [0] = 1
a[0] [1] = 2
a[1] [0] = 3
a[2] [0] = 4
a[3] [0] = 9
a[3] [1] = NULL
```

and again convert those

```
a[0] [0]
a[1] [0]
a[2] [0]
```

into an variable like

```
//values of a[0] a[0], a[1] [0], a[2] [0]
test = '1,3,9'
```

using javascript.

Comment: How are you getting your indices?  It would be easy to turn it into a simple one-dimensional array, using just `.split(', ')`.  But I can make no sense of your indices.

Comment: `string.split(', ')`?

Comment: string.split: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Look at the indices, folks.  This is not as simple as a `split`.

Comment: Are you trying to make a 2-column 2D array? If so, your indexes are off.

Comment: You say `a[2][0]` is `4` in the first example and then you say it `9` in the second. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a multi-dimensional array...? Use split to return an array from a comma separated string.

```
var a = '1, 2, 3, 4, 9, NULL';
var b = a.split(', ');
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point... not that I really understand the point myself.  But the requested output is not this simple array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the reasoning for your indices but the following should result in your desired output.

```
var a = '1, 2, 3, 4, 9, NULL';
var b = a.split(',');
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    array[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        array[i][j] = b[i * 2 + j];
    }
}
console.log(array); //outputs a[0] [0] = 1, a[0] [1] = 2, a[1] [0] = 3, a[1] [0] = 4, a[2] [0] = 9, a[2] [1] = NULL
var test = '';
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(i>0) test=test+',';
    test = test + array[i][0];
}
console.log(test); //outputs 1, 3, 9
```

This won't trim and remove spaces from the strings, but you can do that yourself it is really necassary.

Comment: If it's as arbitrary as that, I'd just as soon do `return [[1, 2], [3], [4], [9, "NULL"]];` and be done with it.

Comment: Amen. The reasonings behind the array and strings he wants makes no sense. I figure whatever numbers he provided isn't the real data and that he could modify the code posted to work for him. The `a[2][0]` and `a[3][0]` make no sense though and seem like a typo. Because in one place in the question `a[2][0]` is `4` and another place it is `9`.